# How to process space at the head of line in file under shell?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script to process old_file into new_file, I want to rewrite one line in old_file like this:

```
old_file:

123
  abc
e45

new_file:

123
  abc bca
e45
```

So I use codes like this:

```
cat old_file | while read line; do process "$line" > new_file; done
```

The process is a function to match and rewrite the line. But I found the space in the head of line in old_file is missing like this:

```
new_file:

123
abc bca
e45
```

So I change code into this:

```
echo "`cat old_file`" | while read line; do echo "$line" > new_file; done
```

But the lines in old_file will be one line(as "" works, sometimes this will got "File name too long" error), I want to process lines one by one, not whole lines together.

So how to process lines in old_file one by one, and at the same time, keep space in the head of line?

Thank you~

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do here? Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: `(while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <old_file) > new_file`? or `sed -i.bak 's/^\s*abc$/& bca/' old_file > new_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your edit, there are several issues. First, you are using the wrong tool for the job. If you want to change the line `'  abc'` to `'  abc bca'`, then `sed` is the correct tool. For example, given `old_file`,

```
$ cat old_file
123
  abc
e45
```

You can accomplish what you want with a simple

```
$ sed 's/^\s*abc$/& bca/' old_file
123
  abc bca
e45
```

To edit the file in place, just add `sed -i.bak` to change the file in place while saving `old_file.bak` containing the original. (you can omit `.bak` and skip creating the backup)

Next, your command `cat old_file` is an *Unnecessary Use Of cat* (a *UUOc*). Simply redirect the file to your loop, e.g.

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <old_file
```

**note:** `read` skips leading whitespace. To preserve, if your shell (e.g. bash, etc.) provides an Internal Field Separator for *word-splitting*, setting `IFS=` will preserve leading whitespace, e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <old_file
```

Otherwise, check the options of your `read` implementation.

Next, after you `process "$line"` to add the `' bca'` you can simply redirect all output to `new_file`. Running the `while` loop in a subshell allows you to redirect the entire output to `new_file`, e.g.

```
(while IFS= read -r line; do process "$line"; done <old_file) >new_file
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.